# How include in jar test class and all dependency?

Tags: maven, testing, junit, jar

i use IntelliJ for a project with many modules:

```
  Root
    |-->Module1
    |-->Module2
    |-->Module3
    pom.xml
```

Eache Module has a pom.xml. and has also Test Class in src\test\java*.

My parent's pom.xml is this:

```
<groupId>it.anas.testSuite</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestSuite</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>TestSuite</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.test.skip.exec>true</maven.test.skip.exec>   <---this for no run test when i do mvn install
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>SimulatorFrontEndTest</module>
        <module>SmartRoadApiTest</module>
        <module>SimulRestTest</module>
        <module>SmartRoadSimulatorTest</module>
    </modules>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>8</source>
                <target>8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

with maven-jar-plugin when ido MVN PACKAGE i obtain 3 jar without test class and so dependencies..
In intelliJ i'm able to create 3 jar include test in CREATE ARTIFACT and INCLUDE TEST WITH DEPENDENCY (in each pom.xml in module).
I must put dependency in parent's pom.xml or in each module pom.xml?
this is pom module1:
    ....
    
        it.anas.testSuite
        TestSuite
        0.0.1

```
<artifactId>SimulatorFrontEndTest</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>SimulatorFrontEndTest</name>



<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>4.12.0-M4</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
        <!--<version>${junit.platform.version}</version>-->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <!--plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin-->

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    </build>
```

i want genereate :

jar1 (module1) for module1 with this dependencies.

jar2 (module2) with his dependencies.

jar3 (module3) with his dependencies.

when i do mvn package in this project folder.

Thanks

Comment: Test classes are not meant to be packed into a jar. You run them during the build (which you deactivated with `maven.test.skip`). Why do you want to put them into jars?

Comment: i resolved with maven.test.skip.exec..
But now i want include also all dependency and src/test/resource Folder.. How change my pom.xml? thanks

Comment: My question was: Why do you want test classes or test resources in your jars? What is the use case?

Comment: i must use this class in an external project that search and run Test..
Is possible?

Comment: To use classes in external projects, construct a separate project that contains the classes in `src/main/java`. Then you can use them without a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212842/discussion-between-catanzaro-and-jf-meier).

Comment: I did not say that it is not possible. But before one should ask "is it possible?" one should ask "is it a good idea?" And in Maven, the directory `src/test/java` is for test classes that are run during the build, not for test classes run at some other place somewhere later. So you are misusing the directory.

Comment: ok java is sheet.Python win again!

Comment: Maven has clear principles. You need not follow them, but then you usually get into problems later. Therefore I defend those principles. Of course, you can use any directory for anything, but this is not how it is meant to be. This has nothing to do with Java programming itself.

Comment: ok then say me: how include also test dependencies in jar?

Comment: You did not give me a reason why this is a good idea.

Comment: I don't help people with technical problems when I think they are completely on the wrong path. More often than not, people with obscure technical questions are just misusing Maven. I offer guidance to use Maven the right way.

Comment: so for you i must move all class in src/main?

Comment: i move all class in src/main/java.. but when i do mvn package in jar i dont have all dependencies.. congratulation!

Comment: Dependencies of scope `test` will not be present. That is only natural.

Comment: so i cant do a jar executable from windows with only Test? Incredible!

Comment: `test` scope is meant only for running tests during the build. It makes no sense to package these dependencies into an executable. Why would you mark a dependency with scope `test` if you want to use it outside the tests running in the build?

Comment: i move all class in src/main/java and with maven-assembly i include also dependencies but how include also RESOURCE FOLDER?

Comment: Let's keep things civil please

Comment: Usually, the resources from `src/main/resources` should become part of the final jar.

Comment: no because java is sheet.. the world use java but puthon is better..ah ah ah java A A A